# angular2 pipe and directive highlightterm is not working in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular2-directives, angular2-pipe

Hi am try to achieve to filter search term it should be highlight the text so i used first directive and now switched to pipe to test in IE11 browser below is the code.**But below code is working in fine in chrome and firefox am not sure why am  gettting this error in IE11**.kindly help some one to over come this error am using angular2 2.2.3

highlight.pipe.ts:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, search): string {
    if (search && text) {
      let pattern = search.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
      pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
        return t.length > 0;
      }).join('|');
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

      return text.replace(regex, (match) => `<span class="search-highlighterm">${match}</span>`);
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  }
}
```

component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'xxx',
    template:
    `
<span class="title" [innerHTML]="text | highlight: searchTerm">{{text}}'
)
```

or if i use directive like below

```
<span class="title" [highlight]="search" >{text}}
```

am getting error like below

```
- inline template:6:102 caused by: Invalid argument.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument.
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Invalid argument.
   at DomRenderer.prototype.setText (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:42348:67)
   at DebugDomRenderer.prototype.setText (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:71926:72)
   at View_xxxxx1.prototype.detectChangesInternal (Function code:326:5)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChanges (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:73431:9)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:73524:13)
   at ViewContainer.prototype.detectChangesInNestedViews (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:73616:17)
   at View_xxxxx0.prototype.detectChangesInternal (Function code:114:3)
   at AppView.prototype.detectChanges (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:73431:9)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.detectChanges (https://localhost:8080/vvv/js/webpack-bundles/vendor.bundle.js:73524:13)
```

Comment: Check out here [link angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14697)

Comment: @YordanNikolov i saw the link is there any workaround to over come this??

Answer (score 0):

As I cant see what was you try with Directive, here is my solution. I cant test it on IE cause I'm with Ubuntu.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
class WrapBold implements OnInit {
  @Input('highlight') 
    public set search (val: string) {
      this._search = val;
      this.highlightText();
    }
    public get search () : string {
      return  this._search;
    }

  private originEl: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.originEl = this.el.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    this.highlightText();
  }

  private highlightText () {
    if (this.search && this.originEl) {
      let pattern = this.search.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
      pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
        return t.length > 0;
      }).join('|');
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
      console.log(this.originEl); 
      return this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.originEl.innerHTML.replace(regex, (match) => `<strong>${match}</strong>`);
    }
  }
}
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [highlight]="search">
      Hello Angular2
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  search = 'angu';

  constructor() {
    // change the search string after 3sec
    setTimeout(() => { this.search = 'angular'; }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: i think the error is due to if we bind some custom directive or pipe to an dom  element or am i wrong??

Comment: I hope that you are wrong ;]] ... did you test this ?